# How can one avoid duplicating class template specification for each member function?

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a template class specification like so,

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    void fun1();
    // ...
    void funN();
};

template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::fun1() {
    // definition
}

// ...

template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::funN() {
    // definition
}
```

If I change the class template to something else, say I add an extra parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class MyClass {
    // ...
};
```

Then I have to change each function definition (fun1, ..., funN) to agree with the class template specification:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void MyClass<T,U>::fun1() { //... }
```

Are there any strategies for avoiding this? Could I use macros e.g.

```
#define DFLT_TEMPLATE template<typename T, typename U>
#define DFLT_CLASS  class<T,U>

DFLT_TEMPLATE
void DFLT_CLASS::fun1() { // ... }
```

Or is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Don't care about what other say. If you **really hate** rewriting things multiple times (like me) - then just use macros. I'm aware of all the drawbacks and pitfalls of using macros. However I still prefer macros to copy+paste and etc.

Comment: P.S. From my personal experience rewriting things, apart from demoralization, is much more dangerous than using macros

Comment: There is a clean solution: Just place all definitions inside the class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, the benefits of using a macro here are far overshadowed by the drawbacks.  Yes, if you use a macro then if you ever need to add an additional template parameter, you'll only need to make a single modification.  But anyone else reading your code is probably going to vomit.

I mean, are you going to do this for *every* template you have?  Your code will become infested with ugly macros.

Comment: +1 and pretty much what I was typing when you hit the button. :)

Answer (score 2):

***How many member functions*** do you have that this is an issue?

I think either ***they are small enough to be defined within the class template*** or the adaption of their ***algorithms*** to an additional template parameter would by far outweigh the replacement of those function headers.

Also, your editor ought to do this for you in no time anyway.

Comment: Regarding outsourcing, I think that calling externally defined functions would be fine too: provide a template version and let people overload it for their custom types if they wish. After all that's what `Boost` does for `hash_value`, for example, and that's what we already use for `swap`.

Answer (score 1):

yes you could but don't forget to use "#undef DFLT_TEMPLATE" and "#undef DFLT_CLASS" at the end of file to avoid compiler warnings if your project have several templates with same macros definitions

Answer (score 1):

Inheritation is better than macro.

If you want to change only a few functions and variables, make the specialized class inherit a common class that provides common functions/variables.

Answer (score 1):

As far as possible, put the function definitions in the class template definition. It's a template, so unless you're using Comeau compiler, it's not as if they're going to be off in a different TU.

If the functions use something which is defined in between the class definition and the function definition, then you can play tricks to make that thing dependent on a template parameter even when "really" it isn't. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void usebar();
};

struct Bar {
    int a; 
    Foo<int> circularity; // circular dependency between Foo and Bar
    Bar() : a(3) {}
};

template <typename T> void Foo<T>::usebar() {
    Bar b;
    std::cout << b.a << "\n";
}
```

Becomes:

```
// we only have to write "same" once
template <typename T, typename U>
struct same {
    typedef U type;
};

struct Bar;

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void usebar() {
        typename same<T,Bar>::type b;
        std::cout << b.a << "\n";
    }
};

struct Bar {
    int a; 
    Foo<int> circularity; // circularity gone
    Bar() : a(3) {} 
};
```

Or actually in this case just:

```
struct Bar;

template <typename T, typename B = Bar>
struct Foo {
    void usebar() {
        B b;
        std::cout << b.a << "\n";
    }
};

struct Bar {
    int a;
    Foo<int> circularity;
    Bar() : a(3) {}
};
```

All cases support the following code:

```
int main() {
    Foo<int> f;
    f.usebar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this approach bad practice.  What you are complaining about is that you have *changed* your design (you need an extra template parameter) and now want a kludge to save on typing?

Introducing macros is going to decrease the readability of your code.  Preprocessor definitions certainly have their place, but personally I'd never advocate one on the grounds that I can't be bothered to change my functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some (more or less bad) workarounds, but you definitely point out a " missing" feature of C++: `class namespace extension`.
Some people already proposed to extend C++ in this way:
http://www.lrde.epita.fr/dload//20080709-Seminar/ordy-classnamespaces.pdf

```
namespace foo
{
  class bar
  {
    typedef int baz_t;
    baz_t my_method ();
  };
}
namespace class foo::bar
{
  baz_t my_method ()
  {
  // ...
  }
}
```

--
Using a macro is not a good idea (usual things about macros ....).
I would prefer, at worst, write function members definitions inline in this case, or even better use an editor than can help you easily update your class definition.

Macros are bad because they let you write code editing functions where you are supposed to write programs.
If you want to edit code, use your editor (sed, M-x replace-*, Find&Replace ...)